# Unable to execute SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Job I get error " The command line parameters are invalid"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, sql-job

When I am trying to execute a SSIS package from the SQL Server Agent Job, I get this error:

> Executed as user: WEATRUST\Prod_SSIS_Service.
> Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.7462.6 for 64-bit
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Missing argument for option "project". The command line parameters are invalid.  The step failed.

Also when I am executing the SSIS package directly, it is working as expected. I ran the package without modifying any parameters (run with already set parameter in visual studio) it is working as expected

When I am checking package log, it is not even started, Also checked in system table (`msdb.dbo.jobsteps`) for parameter, I got the following value in command field:

```
/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Ztest\DST_Hedis\PKG_MAIN_DST_HEDIS_Monthly_Load_OUT.dtsx\"" /SERVER "\"EDS-PROJ-DV01\"" /Par "\"$Project::Control_file\"";"\"WEA_ControlTotals\"" /Par "\"$Project::DST_Outbound_FileDir\"";"\"F:\PKG_TEST\DST\\"" /Par "\"$Project::DST_Staging_FileDir\"";"\"F:\PKG_TEST\DST\Staging\\"" /Par "\"$Project::Enrollment_file\"";"\"WEA_Enrollment\"" /Par "\"$Project::Enrollmentdemo_file\"";"\"WEA_EnrollmentDemographics\"" /Par "\"$Project::Pharmacy_file\"";"\"WEA_PharmacyClaims\"" /Par "\"$Project::Providerdemo_file\"";"\"WEA_ProviderDemographics\"" /Par "\"$Project::ServerName\"";"\"EDS-PROJ-DV01\"" /Par "\"$Project::Singleclaim_file\"";"\"WEA_SingleClaims\"" /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E
```

Comment: Why are you using a command to execute the package, and not the inbuilt SSIS Package execution within Agent?

Comment: I am not using any command to execute just created one job and steps through sql server agent job UI, i just checked what it is storing in msdb.dbo.jobsteps to verify how the parameter is passing to package.

Answer (score 0):

you need to select the control.dtsx package that runs the rest of the packages.

[select the package on the job step properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXy3P.png)